# Sort a list by the number of occurrences of the elements in the list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort a list by the number of occurrences of the elements in the list.
When I use this form:

```
A=[2,1,3,4,2,2,3]
A.sort(key=lambda x:A.count(x))  
print(A)
```

the result is not what I want: `[2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3]`.
But, when I write like it using `sorted`:

```
B=sorted(A,key=lambda x:A.count(x))
print(B)
```

the result is right: `[1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2]`.
what's the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Side note, you don't need `lambda`, e.g. `A.sort(key = A.count)`

Comment: This returns the number of occurencies for each element in A: `[A.count(element) for element in set(A)]`

Comment: Using a `Counter` (`A.sort(key=collections.Counter(A).get)`) here would be more efficient and would work for both `sort` and `sorted`.

Comment: Python objects are distinguished two types of that mutable and immutable. If a value in mutable object changes, it affects original data. Because of that `list object` is mutable, the index of data is changing dynamically.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is by design and intentional. CPython temporarily "disallows" access to the list while the list is being sorted in place, the behavior is [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

> **CPython implementation detail:** *While a list is being sorted, the
> effect of attempting to mutate, or even inspect, the list is
> undefined.* The C implementation of Python makes the list appear empty
> for the duration, and raises ValueError if it can detect that the list
> has been mutated during a sort.

You can inspect that by printing `A` inside the key function - you'll get an *empty list*:

```
In [2]: def key_function(x):
    ...:     print(A, x)
    ...:     return A.count(x)
    ...: 

In [3]: A.sort(key=key_function)  
([], 2)
([], 1)
([], 3)
([], 4)
([], 2)
([], 2)
([], 3)
```

But, if you do that for `sorted()`:

```
In [4]: sorted(A, key=key_function)
([2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3], 2)
([2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3], 1)
([2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3], 3)
([2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3], 4)
([2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3], 2)
([2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3], 2)
([2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3], 3)
Out[4]: [1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2]
```

---

It is also documented inside the [`sort()` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b9e40ed1bcce127893e40dd355087cda7187ac27/Objects/listobject.c#L1933):

```c
/* The list is temporarily made empty, so that mutations performed
 * by comparison functions can't affect the slice of memory we're
 * sorting (allowing mutations during sorting is a core-dump
 * factory, since ob_item may change).
 */.
```

Comment: it's not because it's documented that it doesn't suck :)

Comment: This restriction probably shouldn't apply to `key=` functions.  I'd suggest filing a bug report at http://bugs.python.org/

Comment: Whoa! Principle of Least Astonishment violated. An error would be an improvement, imo.

Comment: That doesn't sound like an implementation detail to me.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that `A` is changed during the in-place sort process, so you cannot rely on the value of `A` during the sort process.

Making a copy also works.

```
A=[2,1,3,4,2,2,3]
B=A[:]
A.sort(key=lambda x:B.count(x))
print(A)
```

Confirmed by this line in [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)

> CPython implementation detail: While a list is being sorted, the effect of attempting to mutate, or even inspect, the list is undefined. The C implementation of Python makes the list appear empty for the duration, and raises ValueError if it can detect that the list has been mutated during a sort.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a full answer, seems like more of a guess ;)

Comment: A right guess then :)

Comment: @Chris_Rands it _was_ a guess, but now I've found backup in the documentation :) shoot, accepted answer has it right from the start :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because `A.sort` is modifying the list in place underneath while computing. `sorted()` doesn't modify the list and returns therefore a correct result.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in [`sorted` *creates a list out of the sequence*](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2125) provided and then sorts that based on the key argument (omitting error checking):

```
/* copy sequence provided */
newlist = PySequence_List(seq);

/* get list.sort for the list object */
callable = _PyObject_GetAttrId(newlist, &PyId_sort);

/* call it and then return later on */
v = _PyObject_FastCallKeywords(callable, args + 1, nargs - 1, kwnames);
```

This essentially translates to something like what Jean provided in his answer:

```
B = list(A)
B.sort(key=lambda x: A.count(x))
```

By making that copy `B` and referencing `A` in the `key` function, this removes the restriction imposed by `A.sort` which can't peek in itself.